# Make a long antd button wrap it's content when on smaller screens

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I have a button that has a long title or label, so it streches out and doesn't look the best. It looks specially bad on smaller screens where it goes off screen. This is what the code currently looks like:

```
export function MyComponent() {
  return (
     <section className="my-section">
        <a className="ant-btn ant-btn-primary" href="/somewhere">Button with a very long title or content within it</a>
     </section>
  )
}
```

```css
.my-section > .ant-btn.ant-btn-primary {
  background-color: #f29544;
  border-color: #f29544;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 5px;
}
```

With this CSS, this is what it currently looks like:
[image]

Now, I would like it to wrap the content when it becomes too much and become a "fatter" button with two or more lines within it. How do I do that?

I have tried to add `white-space:pre-wrap`, but this breaks the line and leaves the content outside the button, so there is more to it, I am just not sure what. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I also do think even on larger screens it would probably be better as a fatter button with two lines. How do i get it to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: sandbox please, you can try this template: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-antd-styled-template-n8n96

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split your text inside button into two separated `<span>` tags with `white-space: nowrap` CSS rule.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

button {
  background-color: #f29544;
  border-color: #f29544;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>
<span>Text long long text</span> <span>long long text long long text</span>
</button>
```

Run this code in separated window and try resize/reduce window to observe the behavior.

Comment: Additionally, it might be useful to use non-breaking space: `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 4):

Setting

```
white-space: normal
height: auto
```

seems to do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Css :

```
.ant-btn.ant-btn-primary {
    background-color: #f29544;
    border-color: #f29544;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. The button stayed the same.